# Asp.net Custom Validator

Tags: jquery, asp.net, customvalidator

I am performing both `clientside validation` and `server side validation` using `jquery` and `Asp.net custom validator`, `required field validator`.What i am doing is i display a 'X' next to the tetxbox which has wrong input.This is working fine , my issue is when a textbox has wrong input it shows 'X' as `jquery validation` function fires it , at the same time when he submits the data , custom validator also displays a 'X', so two 'X''X' are displayed like this, This kind of looks odd . So what can i do so that it is displayed properly , should i remove text from `custom validator` and only show `error message` on `validation summary`.any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion keep using both, but just don't show 'X' on your jQuery validation. The Text attribute in the Custom Validator, will be seen in any case when submitting, and the ErrorMessage attribute on that validator, will appear in the summary. I have the same situation, and it works fine.

Hopefully, it helps you.

Comment: thanks , if you are suggesting not to show 'X' on jquery then what is the alternative ,, any ideas

Comment: You're welcome. The alternative is to show your 'X' in the custom validator, when info is submitted. So just to be clear, custom validator exists when you want to validate situations that the other default validators can't do.

Comment: Hi again, if you still want to use jQuery and show something with it, you could e.g., trigger an alert box or set the background color of the wrong input field, in red.

Comment: ,,, ya even m thinking of something like that ,, but the issue is currently i am displaying a label as 'X' and on hover of that 'X' it displays the title of the label as tooltip .. So i was wondering if i remove the label i could loose that functionality .

Comment: The answer below which talks about ClientValidationFunction is more desirable, using this JQuery approach there are two systems interacting which can only cause problems long term, best to use the inbuilt functionality if it does what you want.

Comment: @Krystan Honour: Well, JQuery actually in integrated with asp.net. You can check some of the latest books on asp.net 4.0. Also the Microsoft certification for asp.net requires knowledge of JQuery. So if it is perfectly acceptable from Microsoft it shouldn't bother you.

Comment: Just because you can do something doesn't mean you should @Aristotelis Kostopoulos your tone is also unacceptable in a public forum a mistaken attempt to belittle does you no service at all. It does not change the fact that what I said is totally valid. Also no one said the accepted answer was incorrect what has been said is there is a clearer way to do this. It just becomes harder to maintain if you use both ways that's all

Comment: This OP's question was nothing to do with the rights and wrongs of using Jquery with .net (which of course there is nothing wrong with), it was about how to correctly show error messages when using the CustomValidator. Given that the CustomValidator comes with built in client-side code for showing and hiding messages, it makes no sense to implement your own (using jquery or whatever) unless you need very specific functionality (which the OP doesn't appear to). Doing so will only add complication to the solution and likely cause bugs in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The CustomValidator control has a property called `ClientValidationFunction`. This allows you to call a javascript method that has only one job - to set the IsValid property (of the args parameter) to true or false. The custom validator will take care of the error message for you. There is no need for you to have any jquery for showing and hiding the error. It should just work. Asp.net places some javascript on the page for this purpose so you don't have to.

Note: If you have a second RequireFieldValidator (or any other validator) for the same input, then be aware that you should set the `Display="Dynamic"` property which will ensure that the validator does not consume screen space while it is not being shown (which would cause your other validators messages to be pushed out of position).

For more details of the custom validators `ClientValidationFunction` property, see [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction.aspx)

I hope this helps